# groupby in pandas with different functions for different columns

Tags: python, pandas

Best to illustrate by example:

I would like to aggregate a DataFrame by `col1` and `col2`, summing results on `col3` and `col4` and averaging results on `col5`

If I just wanted to sum on col3-5 I'd use `df.groupby(['col1','col2']).sum()`

Comment: Would be good to have sample data and expected result?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `Groupby.agg()` (or `Groupby.aggregate()`) method for this.

`aggregate()` function can accept a dictionary as argument, in which case it treats the keys as the column names and the value as the function to use for aggregating. As given in [the documentation -](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#applying-different-functions-to-dataframe-columns)

> By passing a dict to aggregate you can apply a different aggregation to the columns of a DataFrame.

Example -

```
import numpy as np
result = df.groupby(['col1','col2']).agg({'col3':'sum','col4':'sum','col5':np.average})
```

Demo -

```
In [50]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,6,7,8],[2,3,4,5,6]],columns=list('ABCDE'))

In [51]: df
Out[51]:
   A  B  C  D  E
0  1  2  3  4  5
1  1  2  6  7  8
2  2  3  4  5  6

In [52]: df.groupby(['A','B']).aggregate({'C':np.sum,'D':np.sum,'E':np.average})
Out[52]:
     C    E   D
A B
1 2  9  6.5  11
2 3  4  6.0   5
```

Comment: Thanks, is there a default type for all columns not mentioned?

Comment: I am sorry didn't get your question.

Comment: Say I want to sum over two specific columns,  and average over all the rest,  without specifically naming them

Comment: I don't think you can do that, but you can use dictionary comprehension to create the dictionary , example - `{k:np.sum if k in {'col3','col4'} else k:np.average for k in df.columns if k not in {'col1','col2'}` .

Comment: Great.  Thank you very much.